# objdump/nm for libtool object (.lo) files

Tags: compilation, libtool, objdump, nm

I compiled an open source library and it turned out that there are unresolved symbols within the generated shared library (.so). The natural next step seemed to me finding out which object has the unresolved symbols, but I could not apply `nm` or `objdump` to the intermediate libtool object files (.lo). Is there any way I can take a look at the list of symbols within .lo files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `nm` or `objdump` on the object files (`.o` files), not the `.lo` files.  The `.lo` files are used by `libtool` and are [text files](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Creating-object-files.html) that can tell you where your object files *really* are:

```
# Name of the PIC object.
pic_object='.libs/libfoo_la-foo.o'

# Name of the non-PIC object
non_pic_object='libfoo_la-foo.o'
```

Since you need to know about a DSO (the `.so` file), the `pic_object` files are probably the ones you want to examine.